# How do I convert this Antlr3 AST to Antlr4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I'm trying to convert my existing Antlr3 project to Antlr4 to get more functionality. I have this grammar that wouldn't compile with Antlr4.9

```
expr        
    : term ( OR^ term )* ;
```

and

```
factor 
    : ava | NOT^ factor | (LPAREN! expr RPAREN!) ;
```

Mostly because Antlr4 doesn't support `^` and `!` anymore. From the documentation it seems like those are

> AST root operator. When generating abstract syntax trees (ASTs), token
> references suffixed with the "^" root operator force AST nodes to be
> created and added as the root of the current tree. This symbol is only
> effective when the buildAST option is set. More information about ASTs
> is also available.
>
> AST exclude operator. When generating abstract syntax trees, token
> references suffixed with the "!" exclude operator are not included in
> the AST constructed for that rule. Rule references can also be
> suffixed with the exclude operator, which implies that, while the tree
> for the referenced rule is constructed, it is not linked into the tree
> for the referencing rule. This symbol is only effective when the
> buildAST option is set. More information about ASTs is also available.

If I took those out it would compile but I'm not sure what do those mean and how would Antlr4 supports it.

`LPAREN` and `RPAREN` is tokens

```
tokens {
    EQUALS = '=';
    LPAREN = '(';
    RPAREN = ')';
}
```

which Antlr4 kindly provides the way to convert that in the error messages but not `^` and `!`. The grammar is for parsing boolean expression for example `(a=b AND b=c)`

I think this is the rule

```
targetingexpr returns [boolean value]
    : expr { $value = $expr.value; } ;

expr returns [boolean value]
    : ^(NOT a=expr) { $value = !a; }        
    | ^(AND a=expr b=expr) { $value = a && b; }
    | ^(OR a=expr b=expr) { $value = a || b; }
    | ^(EQUALS A=ALPHANUM B=ALPHANUM) { $value = targetingContext.contains($A.text,$B.text); }
    ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The v3 grammar:

```
...

tokens {
    EQUALS = '=';
    LPAREN = '(';
    RPAREN = ')';
}

...

expr        
    : term ( OR^ term )* ;

factor 
    : ava | NOT^ factor | (LPAREN! expr RPAREN!) ;
```

in v4 would look like this:

```
...

expr        
    : term ( OR term )* ;

factor 
    : ava | NOT factor | (LPAREN expr RPAREN) ;

EQUALS : '=';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
```

So, just remove the inline `^` and `!` operators (tree rewriting is no longer available in ANTLR4), and move the literal tokens in the `tokens { ... }` sections into own lexer rules.

> I think this is the rule
>
> ```
> targetingexpr returns [boolean value]
>     : expr { $value = $expr.value; } ;
>
> expr returns [boolean value]
>     : ^(NOT a=expr) { $value = !a; }        
>     | ^(AND a=expr b=expr) { $value = a && b; }
>     | ^(OR a=expr b=expr) { $value = a || b; }
>     | ^(EQUALS A=ALPHANUM B=ALPHANUM) { $value = targetingContext.contains($A.text,$B.text); }
>     ;
> ```

What you posted there is part of a tree grammar for which there is no equivalent. In ANTLR4 you'd use a visitor to evaluate your expressions instead of inside a tree grammar.

Comment: So Antlr4 has mo equivalent of ^ and !?

Comment: There is no equivalent. You need to construct your own AST if you need an AST via a tree walker of the CST. However, you just seem to synthesize a boolean with your action code, so there's no need for an AST--work off the CST.